# headless chromedriver python "uncaught tagerror"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

chrome_options.add_argument('--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36"')
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

driver.get('https://www.mycarinfo.com.my/Valuation/SearchVehicle?version=free')
```

Running the code on Windows 7, Python 3.6.4, Selenium 3.9.0, Chromedriver 2.43 The code executes without issue in non-headless mode. In headless mode, executed in Anaconda Prompt, outputs the following error continuously:

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1):

Since you're running on windows, you'll need to add the `--disable-gpu` argument when using headless. See https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome

In selenium version `3.9` which you say you're using, you can also use the convenience method `set_headless()` which will add both `--headless` and `--disable-gpu` for you. In newer versions it's a setter `options.headless = True`

Comment: tried the `chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")` . same error

Comment: My guess is because you have the `--disable-extensions` option. Looks like something is causing chrome to be unhappy